# Is there an official Google Cloud Builder with python in it?

Tags: google-cloud-build

The Google cloud builders are listed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders). Is there one with python?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it is not documented but I found out that you can use the go image for this:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint python gcr.io/cloud-builders/go:debian --version
Python 2.7.13
```